在这句话中如何理解 accompany，该怎么翻译这句话
在下面这句话中如何理解 accompany，该怎么翻译这句话

This book evolved from a set of notes written to accompany
a one-semester course in laboratory electronics
at Harvard.

Thank you.

This book evolved from a set of notes written to accompany a one-semester course in laboratory electronics at Harvard.
The two verbs "evolve" and "accompany" are critical in this sentence. There is also a word of the period "one-semester". The translation in Chinese should express the meaning of those words.
这本书是由一套课程笔记演绎(发展)出来的。它是伴随着哈佛大学一学期的实验电子学课程而(逐渐)写成的。

感觉你这个中文翻译很地道，句子也通顺。另外你用英文给出了翻译时应该注意的要点(or 关键点 or critical)，侧重的词语也用加粗显示出来了，这个答案很好，我对这个答案很满意，非常感谢你的答案。

Google uses '配合' for the translation for 'accompany' in this context, which is acceptable

配(to pair up)

合(join together)

配合 (coordinate --> work together --> accompany)


These notes were written to (coordinate with --> work together with --> accompany) the course

感谢您的答案，一个配加上一个和的解释感觉不太容易接受，请问有没有适合这个上下文语境关于accompany的准确定义？

This book evolved from a set of notes.
这本书是由许多小笔记演变而成。
The book was written to accompany a one-semester course in laboratory electronics at Harvard.
这本书是为配合哈佛大学一学期的实验室电子学课程而写。

感谢您的答案，请问你翻译的第二个句子怎么没有看到体现accompany的词语呢？

另外原文中的notes在你写的第二个句子中也缺失了。

Fat fingers typing on a phone! Corrected, I hope!

I refresh this page, then I see it.

When performing translation, we need to pay attention to, and sort through, the root meanings of the words in doubt:
"This book evolved from a set of notes written to accompany(be present and associated with) a one-semester course in laboratory electronics at Harvard."

這本書是由課堂筆記演進, 為(了)伴同/隨哈佛電子實研室一學期的課程而寫(的).


感谢你的答案，请问在这个上下文中，accompany可以翻译为“补充”吗？

I don't think so. Follow the link to see the equivalent English words for “补充”.  http://dict.cn/%E8%A1%A5%E5%85%85

Thank you for your view and link.

You are welcome.
